# Finding the Windows 7 product key

Tags: windows-7, license-key

I'm doing a hard drive upgrade and it might ask me for the product key again.  How can I find it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Either the sticker that came with your machine and/or on the media case.

You can also try [Nirsoft ProduKey](http://nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) for a software way.

Comment: Windows 7 comes on DVDs. CDs as a distribution means for Windows Operating Systems are a thing from the past. :)

Comment: Oh come on!... But true I suppose!

Comment: Magic Jellybean FTW!

Comment: Magic Jelly Bean is awesome.  It instantly shows me the product key for Windows 7 as well as the other Microsoft products installed on my system.

Comment: Just watch out for its installer trying to install some crapware browser toolbar and mess with your default homepage.

Comment: A note for future readers: If this (or any other) tool tells you that your key is `BBBBB...`, it's because it's a volume license (probably bought in bulk by a company, like your computer manufacturer). There's no way to get this key back.

Answer (score 8):

**[Product Key Finder](http://www.ottsolutions.com/products.htm)** is a free tool that will display the installed Windows Product Key and other important Windows system information. Product Key Finder works with the following **Windows** operating systems (2000, 2003, XP, Vista, 2008, **7**), **32-bit and 64-bit**.

Find alternative methods here:

**[How To Find the Windows 7 Product Key Code](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/ht/windows-7-key.htm)**

You may also want to backup your Windows activation files:

**[How to Backup and Restore Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 Activation Status](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/09/24/how-to-backup-and-restore-windows-7-and-server-2008-r2-activation-status-activate-offline-on-reinstall/)**

Comment: ottsolutions' "Product Key Finder" is nice because it doesn't need to be installed, and doesn't install any crapware either.

Answer (score 2):

This short PowerShell script by [Winaero](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-get-the-windows-product-key-without-using-third-party-software/) can be used.

See [the blog post](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-get-the-windows-product-key-without-using-third-party-software/) for step-by-step instructions if you're not familiar with PowerShell.

```
function Get-WindowsKey {
    ## Function to retrieve the Windows Product Key from any PC
    ## by Jakob Bindslet (jakob@bindslet.dk)
    param ($targets = ".")
    $hklm = 2147483650
    $regPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
    $regValue = "DigitalProductId"
    Foreach ($target in $targets) {
        $productKey = $null
        $win32os = $null
        $wmi = [WMIClass]"\\$target\root\default:stdRegProv"
        $data = $wmi.GetBinaryValue($hklm,$regPath,$regValue)
        $binArray = ($data.uValue)[52..66]
        $charsArray = "B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","M","P","Q","R","T","V","W","X","Y","2","3","4","6","7","8","9"
        ## decrypt base24 encoded binary data
        For ($i = 24; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
            $k = 0
            For ($j = 14; $j -ge 0; $j--) {
                $k = $k * 256 -bxor $binArray[$j]
                $binArray[$j] = [math]::truncate($k / 24)
                $k = $k % 24
            }
            $productKey = $charsArray[$k] + $productKey
            If (($i % 5 -eq 0) -and ($i -ne 0)) {
                $productKey = "-" + $productKey
            }
        }
        $win32os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $target
        $obj = New-Object Object
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Computer -value $target
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Caption -value $win32os.Caption
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty CSDVersion -value $win32os.CSDVersion
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty OSArch -value $win32os.OSArchitecture
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty BuildNumber -value $win32os.BuildNumber
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty RegisteredTo -value $win32os.RegisteredUser
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty ProductID -value $win32os.SerialNumber
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty ProductKey -value $productkey
        $obj
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be the accepted answer! Simple and no extra tools required!

Answer (score 1):

[Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html).

Download, install, run it, then it opens a page in your web browser displaying *all kinds* of facts and statistics about your PC...near the bottom, it has all the product keys, etc for all the install software, and, of course, the operating system...Hope that helps!

Comment: but note: ["We do not permit use of the Belarc Advisor for commercial purposes"](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html#faq)