# Reinstalling Windows 7 (Removing Bloatware)

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, bloatware

I have the following problem, I recently bought a new laptop (a Lenovo Ideapad) and it seems as if it came without a Windows 7 Installation disk (though it is on the laptop). The problem is that I usually reinstall the OS to get rid of all the bloatware, but without the Windows 7 CD, I don't know how to get rid of all of the bloatware. I know of PC Decrapifier; not sure how well that works; would have preferred to just reinstall the OS, but I was wondering if there was anyway of doing this without having the actual CD, but having a genuine copy.

Comment: There's not THAT much bloatware on a Lenovo.  Certainly not compared to everybody else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the product key ? Download an OEM edition DVD from the *usual sources* and reinstall Windows 7, using your product key. Refer to a previous Super User question [on recovering Windows 7 Product key](https://superuser.com/questions/87849/finding-the-windows-7-product-key)

> Either the sticker that came with your
> machine and/or on the media case.
>
> You can also try [Magic Jelly Bean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) for a software way.

Comment: Just a fyi, not all keys work with different oem versions of the dvd.

Comment: Or you can download a retail version and edit `ei.cfg`...

Comment: For completeness, it might be worth suggesting that he/she backs up their original drivers before the re-install using something like Double Driver (http://www.boozet.org/dd.htm). The last thing you want is to have a poorly functioning fresh install because you're missing a key driver.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I've had no problems with PC Decrapifier. First thing I run on all installs from the manufacturer.

Comment: Well I hate how they set up the partitions anyway...

Comment: The Manufacturer? That extra partition is usually a recovery partition. Easy way to reinstall without having to worry about drivers, even if you have to decrapify the PC again.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a new 64 bit Windows 7 Home Premium and ran PC Decrapifier with no problems at all, as the first thing done, after installing Microsoft Security Essentials (instead of the Norton 60 day trial), and running Windows Updates.

There was some non-installed bloatware not found, such as E-bay, ISP providers, etc., but I was able to determine what they were and remove myself.

I am now in the process of installing my essential freeware, after checking for 64 bit versions, and then my production software. So far, I have not found anything I used in XP or Vista 32bit versions that does not work, or have a 64 bit version to use instead.