# How to find windows 7 product key

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the Windows 7 product key](https://superuser.com/questions/87849/finding-the-windows-7-product-key)

I have bought a Toshiba laptop and I wasn't aware that the license number is the same as the product key number; the problem is now that I can't read the license number as it's been almost deleted so is there any other way to know the license number / product key number?

Many thanks

Comment: There are many applications on the internet that do this, of course I would not suggest using any of them, because most of them are connected to less then moral actions ( i.e. piracy ).  I suggest you contact Toshiba for your product key.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the free version of [Magical Jelly Bean](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) works well to gather various Windows keys from your registry.

It will grab the key for your OS, as well as any Office products

Answer (score 0):

You can also try ProduKey which allows you to retrieve not only windows key but also office keys. [ProduKey link](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Enchanted Keyfinder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ekeyfinder/) is an open source fork of Magical Jelly Bean, since Magical Jelly Bean went the route of a paid tool.