# Recovering Windows 7 Product Key from Registry Backup

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, product-key

My SSD gave up a little while back and I would like to recover my Win 7 Product Key from the drive.  Even using recovery software, I was unable to recover my Windows/System32/config directory which I think would have been useful for programs like ProduKey mentioned in this [product key recovery question](https://superuser.com/questions/87849/finding-the-windows-7-product-key).

However, interestingly, I was able to recover my Windows/System32/config/RegBack folder.  Is there any way to get at the key from these files?  I can't seem to use them with ProduKey directly.

Comment: I had more time to work on this and still no luck.  Any way to read a back -up registry and get the product key out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product key was recoverable.  While the backup SOFTWARE file was not readable in its form (thanks for the idea though @whs),  there is a utility called [MiTec](http://www.mitec.cz/wrr.html) that can read the file.  The product key can be extracted from the Windows Installation tag in the program.

Answer (score 0):

If this an OEM Windows 7, then the product key that's in the system will not be of any use. That is a generic key used at the factory to activate thousands of systems. The key that counts for this PC is on the COA sticker which looks like this.

[image]

This sticker is on the bottom of laptops or in the battery compartment. On desktops it is usually in the back.

Comment: mmm...  so I built this pc 5 years or so ago.  I have an "OEM system Builder License".  Stupidly, I kept the CD and the manual and wrote some ten alpha-numeric code on the back of it, but not the packaging.

Comment: Or the top. System builder licences do come with 'real' product keys, just much simpler packaging/

Comment: Hmm, in other words you lost the product key. But did you try this ==> http://www.nthelp.com/Win98_product_key_recovery.htm

Comment: Ok I tried this.  The backup registry is not in a readable form.