# Using Windows OEM License key on another Laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, license

I have an older Toshiba R-800 laptop that's dying. Before I dispose the laptop, I want to recover the Windows License key. This laptop was given to me at my previous workplace and at some point, they might have replaced the OEM windows installation with an installation of Windows Enterprise (I think?). I'm not entirely sure.

I now have a refurbished laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad) that I purchased 2nd hand. This has Windows 7 Pro. The copy of Windows on the Lenovo was a "trial" version (I'm not entirely sure) and that trial has expired. I keep receiving the error that  this copy of Windows might not be genuine and needs activation. I'd like to activate it using the license key of the Toshiba. I tried entering the serial number that's on the back of the laptop on a sticker but that does not work.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or this is not allowed or perhaps I'm entering the license key incorrectly (The sticker is slightly worn out).

Any idea on how I can use the earlier license on the lenovo laptop?

Edit: I've updated the title to add clarity to my question and also make it clearer on what I'm trying to achieve. The request never has been merely to retrieve the Windows License Key

Comment: You first need to determine if the license on the Toshiba was an OEM copy or not.  Only you can determine that.  If it was an OEM license then it cannot be put on the Lenovo.  If it was the Enterprise license then you would have to format the machine and install Windows 7 Enterprise on it.

Comment: I removed my answer because the application I recommended might have had malware in it.  It was never my intention of having anyone install malware so I removed my answer.  Good luck with your issue.

Comment: @Richie086 Did you recommend Produkey? The Nirsoft site does not bundle malware with their software.

Comment: Yeah try that!  Nirsoft is a great company. I use his stuff all the time

Comment: @Ritchie086  --  Thanks... I know it was unintentional.  It was NOT EASY to even discover it had malware inside that file.     And, yes... I DO trust Nirsoft and will look there. (I already had all his tools and forgot he had a key grabber.)

Comment: This is not a duplicate as I cannot find the product key using the linked question. I've tried all the methods listed there

Comment: @Ramhound I believe it was the OEM license and not the enterprise key license. I'm not sure though. The sticker came originally with the Laptop and was not pasted by my previous employers IT team

Comment: If it was an OEM license then it cannot be transfered to another OEM's hardware.  This is indeed a duplicate of an existing question.  This is proven by the fact you got 2 answers from the linked question.

Comment: @Ramhound understood about the OEM key restriction - I wasn't aware of this. That said, the link question (https://superuser.com/questions/87849/finding-the-windows-7-product-key) does not directly address the issue that I have - which is using the key from one device on another device. The other question only addresses retrieving the key for a HDD upgrade/change which will result in a OS reinstall and hence require a reactivation

Answer (score 0):

Finding a good program without malware is not always easy.  I've trusted Nirsoft in the past, and believe HIS SOFTWARE is safe, effective, and free.  It found my Windows 10 keys from both the HD and the bios, (which were identical numbers.)

**Here's the link to the [Nirsoft Key viewer](http://nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) page, where HIS files can be downloaded directly from near the bottom of the page.** (You can choose to run or install the 32 or 64 bit versions.)

**WARNING ---** There is a ""related Links" near the top of his page that is NOT his program, and instead takes you to the page offering:

> "Recover lost CD keys for Windows and 8000+ major programs - including
>   products of Adobe, Symantec, Autodesk, and more... ".

This free version of MagicJellyBean, published by One UP, Ltd., contains OPENCANDY malware, so DO NOT INSTALL!  Reference  https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/0bd085e0b3578744d427b54d3d30c47ad05d6080f69054f4d917396917446e6a/analysis/1463623576/

Comment: Those are revolving ads, they may never see it. @DaaBoss

Comment: @Moab - Usually, you'd be correct.  In this case however, the link appears to be an affiliate link hardcoded into Nirsoft's site = http://recover-keys.com/en/nirsoft.html

Comment: [I like non-commercial software personally](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/tag/ShowkeyPlus)

Comment: When I run ProduKey, it gives me a message "Product Key was not found" for the Windows Enterprise row. In any case, as I mentioned, I need to use the Win 7 Pro key and not the enterprise key (if at all)

Comment: @Aj - You can't since OEM licenses cannot be transfered between OEMs and they technically can't even be transfered between machines.  Your asking for the impossible.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand this after your comment on the question itself. I was still responding to daaboss as he made the effort to answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past, but only sometimes. ymmv. It is un-intrusive and easy to test though.

From an elevated command prompt, run the following command:

```
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

You might also try running this through Powershell:

```
powershell "(Get-WmiObject -query ‘select * from SoftwareLicensingService’).OA3xOriginalProductKey"
```

[Windows Club: Find Windows Product Key](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/find-windows-product-key)

Comment: This **does not work** on Windows 7. "ERROR:
Description = Invalid query"